# Is pitch-flap coupling an aerodynamic effect or an intrinsic property of a delta 3 offset?

Tags: propeller, flaps, blade, pitch

I am modelling a propeller, in particularly the equations of motion of the various pitch/lag/flap angles as the propeller is turning around. The blade includes a $\delta_3$ angle, which provides pitch-flap coupling by offseting the flap hinge slightly (see image below). From what I understand, his  pitch-flap coupling essentialy reduces the flap amplitude by varying the pitch. However, is this an aerodynamic effect? Or an intrinsic effect that is a result of the kinematics.

[image]

Comment: Is this a question about helicopter rotor blades, that would not apply to a typical airplane propeller? If so, the question and title could be clarified by changing the word "propeller" to "rotor", (adding something about "rotor" to title), adding an appropriate tag, etc.  Even if the word "propeller" is not technically incorrect, most readers would benefit from a reference to "rotor" if applicable.

Comment: Short answer before I write something longer, to get a better idea: delta-3 is a mechanical coupling that utilizes the kinematics of the blade flapping to create a pitching moment that, by way of aerodynamics, stabilizes the flapping motion.  I found another answer that talks about this here: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/73318/how-does-a-delta-3-hinge-on-a-helicopter-tail-rotor-work.  Is that what you're asking about?